# StickyGridHeaders bug when used inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-scrollbar

I am using [TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) library and my `StickyGridHeadersGridView` is placed inside a `RelativeLayout`. The problem is, attributes I used in layout XML for `StickyGridHeadersGridView` is not working because of which `ScrollBar` is appearing above the grid view items

```
android:layout_above
android:layout_below
android:layout_toRightOf
```

I am getting output as follows

[image]

**Workaround Solution:**

To resolve this issue I have to wrap the `StickyGridHeadersGridView` inside `FrameLayout` and I applied the above mentioned attributes to this `FrameLayout` and it worked just fine BUT `FrameLayout` here is unnecessary since it will add an Another view in  view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this bug is resolved after replacing the following two lines in `StickyGridHeadersGridView.java` (line no 887)

```
canvas.restore();
canvas.restore();
```

with

```
if (mHeaderBottomPosition != headerHeight) {
    canvas.restore();
}
canvas.restore();
```

Thanks to [TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) [Issue #55](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/issues/55)